# How to not use web guard when using Laravel Sanctum?

Tags: laravel

I changed my default authentication guard to sanctum in config/auth:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'sanctum',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

But the file still has a web guard defined below in 'guards' array:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

The problem is that whenever i try to change or remove this 'web' guard, in run in some kind of problem. Laravel used to have an 'api' guard that used a 'token' driver, but it doesn' t seem to work with Sanctum. If i try something like:

```
'guards' => [
        'sanctum' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => true,
        ],
```

I get error messages when attempting to login:

```
message "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = cf0dbc91d7fd14b67b664a89a7b3a6c303a7b18b48c3deb3889953f2c95ed3e3 limit 1)"
```

I need a guard called 'sanctum' to avoid conflicts with spatie/permissions package, but i can't get rid of this 'web' guard without crashing my application. How can set 'sanctum' (using token based athentication only) in my 'guards' array?

From spatie/permission documentation:

*If your app uses only a single guard, but is not web (Laravel's default, which shows "first" in the auth config file) then change the order of your listed guards in your config/auth.php to list your primary guard as the default and as the first in the list of defined guards. While you're editing that file, best to remove any guards you don't use, too.*

Comment: The web guard is used by the web middleware, if you want to remove it, you will need to remove web middleware everywhere in your routes, i'm not really sure if it's a good idea though. And also you will need the HasApiTokens trait on your user model

Comment: How could i at least set a sanctum guard in the guards[] array before the web one? This is a weird requirement from spatie/permissions. The first guards[] item should be named the same as the default one. Using driver => api doesn't work.

Comment: Well i don't think the orders of guards change anything for laravel, so you should be able to put sanctum first. Did you run `php artisan migrate` after sanctum install ?

Comment: True for laravel, but weridly, not true for this popular Laravel package. I edited the question quoting spatie's documentation.